# How to get latest one record of each unique id in cosmosDB SQL API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Please comment if more explanation or Details required**

I have a CosmosDb SQL API container with around 5 million+ document, where each document in container looks similar to below example.

```
{
"studentId": "ST009",
"name": "Satyam",
"Class": 8,
"Subject": "Mathematics",
"Address": "XYZ"
"contact": "9989126789"
"_ts": 1650372161
}
```

Each Student will have unique studentId, lets assume that the complete documents contains data of 300 students only(i.e. the 5 million+ document is having data of only those 300 students), I need to get only latest document of each student, I need a query that can give me only 300 records based on unique studentId.

Below is the example of the container documents

```
{
"studentId": "ST009",
"name": "Satyam",
"Class": 8,
"Subject": "Mathematics",
"Address": "XYZ"
"contact": "9989126789"
"_ts": 1650372161
}
{
"studentId": "ST008",
"name": "Siddharth",
"Class": 9,
"Subject": "Mathematics",
"Address": "XYZ"
"contact": "9989126789"
"_ts": 1650372152
}
{
"studentId": "ST010",
"name": "Debashis",
"Class": 8,
"Subject": "Science",
"Address": "XYZ"
"contact": "9989126789"
"_ts": 1650372167
}
{
"studentId": "ST009",
"name": "Satyam",
"Class": 8,
"Subject": "Science",
"Address": "XYZ"
"contact": "9989126789"
"_ts": 1650372169
}
...
```

Comment: can you clarify the question its not clear what the 50 records are

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have clarified my query for you understanding, please let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: If we can use material view, can you let me know how can we do that?

Comment: How can you expect to het the latest document when you have no datetime property in the document? using _ts is possible but its not a good thing to do

Comment: I'm confused. You have a model in which one document stores 300 students and any updates to this document are appended to this container? Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @MattDouhan, if I add a TimeStamp property to each document, then can you tell me the further  procedure.